# bootstrap date time picker change format

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, date

I'm using a bootstrap date time picker to select a date with the time his format is like this **mm/dd/yyyy hh:ii** i want to change this format to **dd/mm/yyyy hh:ii**

I had used this method but i didn't have the format i want the same format still appear

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                       format: "dd/mm/yyyy hh:ii"
                });
            });
        </script>
```

**Html Code:**

```
<input type="text" value="" id="datetimepicker1" name="txt_padd"
 placeholder="Actual Date" class="form-control input-md" onchange="call()" 
onkeyup="saveValue(this);" >
```

How Can i Change the format of this datetimepicker ??!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/0Ltv25o8/4002/)

```
$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
   format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
//HTML Code with iconic view
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-4">Datetime Picker</label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      <span class="input-group-addon"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> </span> </div>
  </div>
</div>

//Javascript Code
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
      format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'
    });
  });
</script>
```

This will looks like : [image: Datepicker Image]

Comment: its perfectly working for me try it by replacing given css, js. hope this will helps you

http://seantheme.com/color-admin-v2.0/admin/html/assets/plugins/bootstrap-eonasdan-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css

http://seantheme.com/color-admin-v2.0/admin/html/assets/plugins/bootstrap-eonasdan-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css